# Typeahead using object name

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to setup a `typeahead` using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) & [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) like so:

.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedStuff" typeahead="stuff.name for stuff in stuffs | filter:$viewValue"/>

<span>{{selectedStuff.name}}</span>
<span>{{selectedStuff.desc}}</span>
```

.js

```
$scope.stuffs= [
                {
                 "name":"thing1",
                 "desc":"this is the first thing"
                },
                {
                 "name":"thing2",
                 "desc":"this is the second thing"
                }
               ]
```

Currently, I've been able to update the model with the selected name, but my goal is to pass along the entire object via the `typeahead`. Is there a clean way to do this using only the input?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sure thing :-)

The typeahead directive from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ uses the same super-flexible syntax as the AngularJS [select directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) for `ng-options`. So you could write:

```
typeahead="stuff as stuff.name for stuff in stuffs | filter:$viewValue"
```

Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/5kGZkNPZ7rIFfb4Rvxej?p=preview

Comment: Amazing! Just as simple and awesome as I was hoping. Thank you!

Comment: I'm seeing '[Object object]' in the input box because I have to instantiate it in the controller in order to use it in the controller. If I don't instantiate it, and it's undefined at first, then it displays fine. This is my predicament. Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same error..object object appears after cliking, morgs32 did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Doing something like this `typeahead="item.ItemID for item in items_vendors.items  | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"` helped me, where `ItemID` is what I want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have solved it by

```
typeahead="country.name for country in countryList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
```

here countryList is a list of country object. name is one of property of country object. For me it is working fine.